# Onclick image slider and redirect to website url

Tags: android, image, hashmap, slider, uri

I add a image slider (library by [Daimajia's AndroidImageSlider](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider)) above my ListView. The image slider success to load the image from Drawable. What i want to do is : when click on the specific image, it will redirect me to a website url. Is there any possible way to do so? I tried " if(name == image_name) then Intent ", but its not working. Please Help me on this. Thanks.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements BaseSliderView.OnSliderClickListener  {

     public static final String TAG_CATEGORY = "category";

     Button lifestyle, men, women, books, cars, furnitures, photography, music;
     String life;

     private SliderLayout mSlider;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);

    lifestyle = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_lifestyle);
    men = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_men);
    women = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_women);
    books = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_books);
    cars = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_cars);
    furnitures = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_furnitures);
    photography = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_photography);
    music = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_music);

    mSlider = (SliderLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.slider);

    //HashMap<String,String> url_maps = new HashMap<String, String>();
    //url_maps.put("Car", "http://gemini888.tk/GPFileUpload/uploads/car.jpg");
    //url_maps.put("Camera", "http://gemini888.tk/GPFileUpload/uploads/camera.jpg");
    //url_maps.put("Men", "http://gemini888.tk/GPFileUpload/uploads/men.jpg");
    //url_maps.put("Women", "http://gemini888.tk/GPFileUpload/uploads/women.jpg");

    HashMap<String,Integer> file_maps = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    file_maps.put("Tourist Guide",R.drawable.tourist);
    file_maps.put("Local Food",R.drawable.food);
    file_maps.put("Penang Art",R.drawable.penang);
    file_maps.put("Puchong Food", R.drawable.puchong);


    Drawable resTou = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tourist);
    Drawable resFood = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.food);
    Drawable resPen = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.penang);
    Drawable resPuc = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.puchong);




    for(String name : file_maps.keySet()){
        TextSliderView textSliderView = new TextSliderView(getActivity());
        // initialize a SliderLayout
        textSliderView
                .description(name)
                .image(file_maps.get(name))
                .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.Fit)
                .setOnSliderClickListener(this);

        //add your extra information
        textSliderView.getBundle().putString("extra",name);

       mSlider.addSlider(textSliderView);
    }
    mSlider.setPresetTransformer(SliderLayout.Transformer.Accordion);
    mSlider.setPresetIndicator(SliderLayout.PresetIndicators.Center_Bottom);
    mSlider.setCustomAnimation(new DescriptionAnimation());
    mSlider.setDuration(4000);




    lifestyle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View rootView) {


            Intent a = new Intent(getActivity(), Category_product.class);
            startActivity(a);

        }
    });

    men.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View rootView) {

            Intent b = new Intent(getActivity(), Men_product.class);
            startActivity(b);

    }
    });

    women.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View rootView) {

            Intent b = new Intent(getActivity(), Women_product.class);
            startActivity(b);

    }
    });

    books.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View rootView) {

            Intent b = new Intent(getActivity(), Books_product.class);
            startActivity(b);

    }
    });

    cars.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View rootView) {

            Intent b = new Intent(getActivity(), Cars_product.class);
            startActivity(b);

    }
    });

    furnitures.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View rootView) {

            Intent b = new Intent(getActivity(), Furnitures_product.class);
            startActivity(b);

    }
    });

    photography.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View rootView) {

            Intent b = new Intent(getActivity(), Photography_product.class);
            startActivity(b);

    }
    });

    music.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View rootView) {

            Intent b = new Intent(getActivity(), Music_product.class);
            startActivity(b);

    }
    });


    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onSliderClick(BaseSliderView slider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //Intent touristIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",Uri.parse("http://m.mygp.la/mr/m.aspx?m=MelakaTouristGuide"));
    //Intent touristIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),AllProductActivity.class);
    //startActivity(touristIntent);



}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use switch(position) {
case 1 :
      **intent**

}

Comment: i used int position = 0;
  
  switch(position) {
  
  case 0 :
   Intent tourist = new Intent(getActivity(), AllProductActivity.class);
   startActivity(tourist);
   break;
   }

Answer (score 0):

I have no reputation to put comment and so put it as answer and see if it helps:
1. I think you want to compare String, so it should be "if(name.equals(image_name))". "if(name == image_name)" is checking for the same object.

Comment: Sry im new to android. How to set that onClick i will get the "name" which used to do compare?